# Why do we need edit logs for maintaining the changes in HDFS

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, hadoop2

Why do we require a mediator for writing down the changes in HDFS. Why cant the changes be directly written to FSimage. Why do we require a mediator in between. Kindly help

Answer (score 0):

It is used at the time of the Checkpointing.

> A typical edit ranges from 10s to 100s of bytes, but over time enough edits can accumulate to become unwieldy. A couple of problems can arise from these large edit logs. In extreme cases, it can fill up all the available disk capacity on a node, but more subtly, a large edit log can substantially delay NameNode startup as the NameNode reapplies all the edits. This is where checkpointing comes in.

Checkpointing is a process that takes an fsimage and edit log and compacts them into a new fsimage. This way, instead of replaying a potentially unbounded edit log, the NameNode can load the final in-memory state directly from the fsimage. This is a far more efficient operation and reduces NameNode startup time.

However, creating a new fsimage is an I/O- and CPU-intensive operation, sometimes taking minutes to perform. During a checkpoint, the namesystem also needs to restrict concurrent access from other users. So, rather than pausing the active NameNode to perform a checkpoint, HDFS defers it to either the SecondaryNameNode or Standby NameNode, depending on whether NameNode high-availability is configured. The mechanics of checkpointing differs depending on if NameNode high-availability is configured; we’ll cover both.

Read the [link](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.4.1/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HdfsUserGuide.html) for more details